# How to specify MDX set by property range?

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to create a named set representing the next 12 fiscal months. I have `[Fiscal Month]` with `[Fiscal Month Ordinal]` as a property, with `'0'` as the current period and positive and negative integers as the future and past, respectively.

I would have expected something like this to work, but a query of this set returns no data:

```
FILTER( [Time].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month], 
        [Time].[Fiscal Month].CURRENTMEMBER.Properties("Fiscal Month Ordinal") = 1)
```

That should be for one period, at least. Leaving aside the need to include the range from 1-12 for the moment.

Comment: I suppose if I can identify the current period, I can bring lag and lead to bear.